# Swift/Swift UI: How do I set the initial value of this optional within my view struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have episode data displayed as a list within a vertical stack.

When the user taps an episode, I want to store that episode as `selected_episode`.

At the top of the view struct, I instantiate my array of episodes from a json file. I then want to ensure that the selected episode is initially the first episode. I thought I could do this in `init()`.

However, it appears that `selected_episode` is never set. In the button action, it won't unwrap because it is always nil.

Where/how do I set the initial value of `selected_episode`?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let episodes = Bundle.main.decode([Episode].self, from: "episodes.json" )
    
    @State private var selected_episode : Episode?

    init() {
      selected_episode = episodes.first
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(episodes) { episode in
                Button(action: {
                    if let obj = selected_episode {
                        if (episode.id != obj.id) {
                            selected_episode = episode
                        }
                    }
          
      ...
```

Comment: You cannot change the value of @State property, but you can initialize it. `_selected_episode = State(wrappedValue: episodes.first)`. And you don't even need to define `selected_episode` as optional since you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the code to load the data into the `init` method
2. Initialize the `@State` property with `State(wrappedValue:)`
3. Please name variables *lowerCamelCase*

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let episodes : [Episode]
    
    @State private var selectedEpisode : Episode?

    init() {
      self.episodes = Bundle.main.decode([Episode].self, from: "episodes.json" )
      _selectedEpisode = State(wrappedValue: episodes.first)
    }
...
```